# Rails redirect_to with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I want to pass parameters (a hash) to `redirect_to`, how to do this? For example:

```
hash = { :parm1 => "hi", :parm2 => "hi" }
```

and I want to redirect to page `/hello`

URL like this: `/hello?parm1=hi&parm2=hi`

Comment: What controller and action does /hello route to?

Comment: Can't you simply do like this?

    redirect_to 'path', :parm1 => "hi", :parm2 => "hi"

Answer (score 27):

If you don't have a named route for /hello then you'll have to hardcode the params into the string that you pass to `redirect_to`.

But if you had something like `hello_path` then you could use `redirect_to hello_path(:param1 => 1, :param2 => 2)`

Comment: Hi,thanks for you reply.But the No. of parameters is not known, so I can not hardcode them..

Comment: you should be able to pass the whole hash of params as one argument to hello_path() and it will write each key,value pair as a parameter

Comment: @ygnhzeus That's why you should use the named path.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of:

```
 redirect_to some_params
```

You can do:

```
 redirect_to url_for(some_params)
```

You're turning the params into a url with `url_for` before passing it to `redirect_to`, so what you pass `redirect_to` ends up being a URL as a string, which redirect_to is happy to redirect to.

**Note well**: I don't understand why `redirect_to` refuses to use params. It used to be willing to use params. At some points someone added something to Rails to forbid it. It makes me suspect that there are security reasons for doing so, and if so, these security reasons could mean that manually doing `redirect_to url_for(p)` has security implications too. But I haven't yet been able to find any documentation explaining what's up here.

**update**: I've found the security warning, but haven't digested it yet: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16170

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way (if it's not a named route) will be:

`redirect_to "/hello?#{hash.to_param}"`

See: http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_param

Answer (score 1):

Simply, pass the hash into an argument in the URL, and in your code parse it to get out all needed values.

```
param_arr = []
hash.each do |key , val|
  param_arr << "#{key}=#{val}"
end
params_str = param_arr.join("&")

redirect_to "http://somesite.com/somepage?#{params_str}"
```

I know this might be very basic way to do it, but hey, it'll get you somewhere :)

Comment: Since we're already using Rails, we might as well use the [`to_param`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_param) method.