# Ruby on Rails redirect_to with own params/values

Tags: rest, redirect, ruby-on-rails-3.2, httprequest

i have a very similar question like this one:
[Rails redirect_to with params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661611/rails-redirect-to-with-params/13886317#13886317)

so, i learned from this thread, that i can add Params to the Controllers redirect_to like this:

```
format.html { redirect_to @order, :test => "test", notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
```

As far as i understood it, with this, i should be able to show the value of :test in the view. 
But if i try to access it like this

```
<p>
  <b>Zahlungsart:</b>
   <%= params[:test] %>
</p>
```

nothing happens.

Also it doesn´t seem to be a part of the parameters cause

```
<%= params.inspect %>
```

just shows

```
{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"orders", "id"=>"32"}
```

I don´t know what exactly went wrong here.... the redirect_to is the one, which is called by default by the Controller´s "create" action.

So far, i fixed this by just defining `$test` which is accessible with `<%= $test %>` in the view... but this seems to be very ugly for me (isn´t it???).

Just to make it clear, the parameter i want to pass to the view is not an instance of a class like the @order in the default definition of the controller is. it´s just a varialbe with a value that i want to pass to the view.
what would be the normal (RESTful <- if i´m understanding this expression in the right way...) way of just adding a param???

Thanks in advance for enlightening me once again ;-)

Greetings

Tobi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like this

```
format.html { redirect_to order_path(@order, :test => "test"), notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
```